# Notify my application when a folder is modified in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, directory

I want the ownership of folders created by my application to remain only with my application.
This is because I am linking my application's data to the folders path.
So either of these 2 solutions are fine with me:

1. Do not allow anybody to modify the folder created by my application.
   Only my application can delete/rename the folder. Modifying it
   through windows explorer should require admin rights.
2. If above solution is not possible, at least my application should be notified of the change so that my application's links are updated.

The question is that whether it is possible to do this in Windows?
I feel language does not play a role, but still if required, I am using Qt in C++ for developing my application.

**EDIT:** Now there are 2 cases of being notified:

a. When my application is running and the folder is modified.

b. When my application is NOT running and the folder is modified (This may be achieved if Windows maintains a log file for changes to a folder. My application can read this log file and understand the changes in the folder).

Actually, I meant to ask specifically for case b, but now reading the answers makes me feel that it may not be possible to get notified for case b.

Comment: There's an app for that.

Comment: Sorry-- I meant 'there's an API for that'.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I wanted! Can you please write this in as an answer so that I can mark it as correct answer? Also, if possible could you please show snippet of a working code in the answer?

Comment: For part b: You can generate and save a listing of the directory tree of the folder you want to track when your program exits. Then read this listing back when you start your program and compare.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, that is what I can do. But if a folder goes missing or its name changes, my application wouldn't know that. The required intent is to be able to identify the changes performed to a folder so that my application is always linked properly to the folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) class to monitoring files and directories for modifications.

```
QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher();
watcher->addPath(QStringLiteral("C:\\Folder"));
QObject::connect(watcher,&QFileSystemWatcher::directoryChanged,[](QString folder) {
    qDebug() << folder;
});
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution for case a. However it seems that there may not be any solution for case b.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I'm think for case b,  you can do something with File System Filter Drivers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I assume with a filter driver windows would have no way to track changes that happened to a folder if the disk was accessed in a different OS instance perhaps booted off a linux USB stick (which can read and write any folder in ntfs unless something like bitlocker is used).

Comment: The change journal idea may help here however I doubt the linux ntfs-3g driver would support this.

Answer (score 3):

Security in Windows is account-based, not application-based. A folder isn't "created by your application"; it's created by the user running your application.

As for being notified, just keep an open handle. That will **prevent** the folder to be changed while you're running. Obviously, when you're not running, you couldn't even be notified.

[edit]
When your app is not running, you need [NTFS change journals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes I get it now. My intention of asking this question was specifically for case b.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: That's the hardest case, but there is a (complex) solution.

Comment: Indeed it is a solution with some limitations though. I think I will just pass on this feature for my application :P

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly be notified upon dirctory changes - there's a specific API for it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It's common to run such monitoring calls in a threads of their own in order to reduce the chance of missing bursts of notifications, and the way you handle that, and any subsequent buffering/signaling to other threads, is a bit broad for SO.

Asynchronous overlapped operation seems to be supported, but I have not tried/tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StorageLibraryChangeTracker API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagelibrarychangetracker?view=winrt-22621) to track for changes to a folder even when our app is not running.
There is a tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/change-tracking-filesystem

If your app use C++, you need create a C++/WinRT component and call those APIs inside that component, then exposed APIs to your host app.